# Simplify not giving expected result

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why doesn't this expression evaluates to `c + d`?

```
Simplify[
  Max[RealAbs[c], RealAbs[c + d]], Assumptions -> d > 0 && d ∈ Reals && c ∈ Reals]
```

I'm using Mathematica 11.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply because the answer isn't `c + d`. If you add the assumption that `c >= 0`, it will return `c + d`. Without that assumption, `c = -1` and `d = 1` is a counterexample of your proposed answer.